# Calculate Number of Hours worked in Tableau

Tags: date, tableau-api, calculated-field, distinct-values

Number of hours is fixed (8) multiplied by the number of distinct days a user has worked.

I need this number as text to insert into a title on a dashboard.

However I need to separate this number by the User filter from another worksheet. When I apply this, I just get the total number of distinct days (not per user).

This is the calculated field I have created so far:

countd(DATETRUNC('day',[_StartDate]))

Comment: try using a Level of Detail calc fixing on user. something like {fixed user : countd(DATETRUNC('day',[_StartDate]))}

Comment: This worked, thank you

Comment: I added it as an answer. Please accept it so others may find it useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a Level of Detail calc fixing on user. something like {fixed user : countd(DATETRUNC('day',[_StartDate]))}